# Astuetz's PagerSlidingTabStrip library still doesn't slide the tabStrip

Tags: android, tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I've added the [PagerSlidingTabStrip library](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) to my project, following the guide but the strip under the tabs doesn't slide (I'm referring to have something like what you can see in the Google Play app). 
Here is my MainActivity:

```
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);

    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

    });
    for (int i = 0; i < mCollectionPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mCollectionPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));

    }
```

**EDIT**:

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener, android.app.ActionBar.TabListener {
CollectionPagerAdapter mCollectionPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
SharedPreferences mPrefs;
final String welcomeScreenShownPref = "welcomeScreenShown";


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mCollectionPagerAdapter = new CollectionPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    final android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    assert actionBar != null;
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_icon3);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name2);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);

    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setViewPager(mViewPager);


}
```

**EDIT2**
tabs_background.xml:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_example"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/tab_color"/>
```

MainActivity:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_icon3);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name2);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);

    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    tabs.setIndicatorColor(android.R.color.white);
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:pstsUnderlineColor="@color/tab_color"
    app:pstsDividerColor="@color/tab_color"
    app:pstsTabBackground="@drawable/tabs_background"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Don't use `tabs.setIndicatorColor(android.R.color.white);`, use `tabs.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));` to set text color instead. As for tabs background, remove `pstsTabBackground` property, and add `android:background="@drawable/tabs_background"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `PagerSlidingTabStrip` you don't need to add tabs to the actionBar. Just cut your code to:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);

PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

The library automatically adds tabs to the actionbar, gets tabs texts from this method:

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return TITLES[position];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Add the `android:layout_below` property to the `ViewPager` and it should work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT2:**

Firstly, create a `selector` in your drawable folder, called `tabs_background.xml` for tabs background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/your_pressed_red_color" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/your_focused_red_color"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/your_red_color"/>

</selector>
```

Then you can customize tabs, by setting properties, you can see it [here](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip), as for your customization:

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:pstsUnderlineColor="@color/your_red_color"
    app:pstsDividerColor="@color/your_red_color"
    app:pstsTabBackground="@drawable/tabs_background">
```

Don't forget to add this line to the parent RelativeLayout `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

And finally, to set text color, do it programmatically:

```
tabs.setTextColor(android.R.color.white);
```

Comment: Actually I did like you said but my tabs are gone

Comment: Yes now I have a Slidin Strip but there are new problems:
1) I have build a style.xml to customize my old tabs that now are gone with those
2) they are under my old tabs and occupies more space (I've added the screenshot in my question)

Comment: I don't see screenshot... But I think you should remove this line `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`

Comment: Sorry It took a while to load the image but now you can see it. Meanwhile I did what you said and now I have the tabs in the correct place but there's still the problem in how I can customize these tabs like the old ones

Comment: What you want to customize?

Comment: The tabs you can see in the left photo (my current tabs of the library) like the old tabs on the right image

Comment: The tabs disappeared again D: even following your edits

Comment: You forgot to add layout_below property again

Comment: Actually there is:
_<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />_

Comment: With customization ? Maybe you use wrong color as a tabs background

Comment: I just copied/pasted your indications: _<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_example"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_color"/>_

Comment: Update your question please with new edits, show your colors. I have no idea

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your main activity is LinearLayout.
it doesn't work in RelativeLayout.
I had the same problem and it did fixed simply ;)